# How to solve this hover out issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to apply a hover in and hover out effect on a button and a div will popup above the hovered button. The popup div will disappear if user hover out of the button.

My problem is that when the popup div pops and the button's hover out event will kick in because the popup div is hovered at the moment.

```
$('.helpImg').hover(function(){
    $(this).css({'cursor': 'pointer'});
    tooltip = $(this).next().attr('id');
    $('#tool').show(150);
}, function (){
    $(this).css({'cursor': 'auto'});
    $('#tool').hide(50);
})
```

the #tool div will hide right after I click the button becasue the div is above the button and it's considered 'hover out'

Anyway to solve this?? Thanks .

**Updated Code**

```
   $('.helpImg').hover(function(){
            $(this).css({'cursor': 'pointer'});
            toolid=$(this).next().attr('id');
            $('#tooltip-' + toolid).show(150);
        },function (){
            $('#toolip-' + toolid).hide(150);
        })
```

I can't hardcode my popup `div` because I don't know the ID unless I hover my `helpImg` element.

Comment: Why are you `$.hover`ing an element `cursor`? Just set it with a class declaration, e.g., `.helpImg { cursor: pointer; }`. Nevermind on the "syntax errors".

Comment: I need to use the jquery to do that.

Comment: Why? You can't add a `style` block or edit a `.css` include file? Also, what is the `tooltip` variable for? Also, you may want http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter and http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave.

Comment: css http://jsfiddle.net/9P585/

Answer (score 1):

This is how you solve issues with hover on different elements etc :

```
var timer;

$('.helpImg').on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $(this).css({'cursor': 'pointer'});
        $('#tool').show(150);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).css({'cursor': 'auto'});
            $('#tool').hide(50);
        }, 300);
    }
});

$("#tool").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        clearTimeout(timer);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).hide(50);
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dtrS8/)

Comment: ty adeneo. Your solution looks good but I just updated my codes. Would you please check how to do it? Thanks a lot. +1 though

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('.helpImg').css({'cursor': 'pointer'}).hover(function(){
    $('#tool').show(150);
}, function (){
    $('#tool').not(':visible').hide(50);
});

$('#tool').mouseout(function(){ this.style.display = 'none'; })
```