# jQuery dropdown div on hover dissapears when you hover on the dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I made a very simple bare-bones dropdown menu in jQuery.  When you hover over the menu button, the sub-menu properly displays, but if you try to move your mouse into the submenu it rapidly dissapears.

Any ideas how to keep that submenu open but at the same time have it close if the user moves their mouse away from the opening icon and NOT into the menu?

```
    var moreCatsHovered = false;

    $(".moreCatsRight").mouseenter(function () {// show pohelp 
            $(".moreCatsRightMenu").fadeIn(100);
        });

    $(".moreCatsRightMenu").mouseenter(function () {// show pohelp 
            moreCatsHovered = true;
        });

     $(".moreCatsRightMenu").mouseleave(function(){ // hide pohelp on mouse out from pohelp

           $(".moreCatsRightMenu").fadeOut(100);
           moreCatsHovered = false;
    });


     $(".moreCatsRight").mouseleave(function(){ // hide pohelp on mouse out from pohelp
            if (moreCatsHovered == false)
                {
                    $(".moreCatsRightMenu").fadeOut(100);
                }
    });
```

Here is my fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/c3qz0eva/

*** EDIT:  I cannot change the HTML structure unfortunately ***

Comment: Just nest the elements, problem solved -> **http://jsfiddle.net/c3qz0eva/1/**

Comment: And it happens because the mouse leaves  `moreCatsRight` when you move the pointer to `moreCatsRightMenu` and the event handler is triggered, as it should be !

Comment: @adeneo very smart!  Actually I can't nest them because I am dynamically editing the content of the moreCarsRightMenu :(

Comment: Then you have a problem that takes a somewhat complicated solution to fix, using a timeout to prevent the element from dissapearing etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014321/how-to-solve-this-hover-out-issue

Comment: @adeneo  Thanks, it does seem it needs a more complex solution.  I will have to just rework my HTML somehow to allow your more simplistic nesting solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 $('.moreCatsRight').on('mouseenter',function(){
      $('.moreCatsRightMenu').fadeIn(300);
    }).on('mouseout',function(event){
        var relatedTarget = $(event.relatedTarget);

        if(typeof relatedTarget != "undefined"){

            if(relatedTarget.hasClass('moreCatsRightMenu')){
                return false;
            }
        }
        $('.moreCatsRightMenu').fadeOut(300);
    });

    $('.moreCatsRightMenu').on('mouseout',function(event){
     var relatedTarget = $(event.relatedTarget);
    if(typeof relatedTarget != "undefined"){        
        if(relatedTarget.hasClass('moreCatsRight')){
            return false;
        }
    }
    $(this).fadeOut(300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".moreCatsRight").mouseleave(function(){ // hide pohelp on mouse out from pohelp
                if (moreCatsHovered == true)
                    {
                        $(".moreCatsRightMenu").fadeOut(100);
                    }
        });
```

Your logic is wrong. notice the change I made on the if statement. I think this is what you're trying to do unless I'm misunderstanding the question.