# div on mouseenter show other div, if other div is hoved keep show on div else hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a simple popover code.

When I mouseenter a div, I want the associated div to show.

If I mouseover that associated div, I want to keep that div showing, else hide associated div.

Currently I have this js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
custom_popover();
});

function custom_popover() {

    $(".asset-container").on("mouseenter", function () {
    $('.popover-content[data-id=' + $(this).children("video").data("id") + ']').fadeIn("fast").delay(1000);

});

    $('.popover-content').hover(function(){
    $('.techinfo').show()
})

    $(".asset-container").on("mouseleave", function () {
    $('.popover-content[data-id=' + $(this).children("video").data("id") + ']').fadeOut("fast");

  });   

}
```

With this code: it is doing everything I want it to, however it is hiding quickly and then showing again, and then hidding. Not smooth and I dont think this is the right way to write this anyways.

Html:

```
<ul class="col-xs-4">

    <li class="thumnail-video">
    <div class="popover-content" data-id="71" style="display: none;">    </div>

<div class="asset-container">

<video class="img-responsive portrait" type="video/mp4" src="https://ternpro-development.s3.amazonaws.com/media/films/71/mobile/3.mp4" data-id="71"></video>

    </div>
</li>

</ul>
<ul class="col-xs-4">

  <li class="thumnail-video">
    <div class="popover-content" data-id="69" style="display: block;">    </div>

<div class="asset-container">

<video class="img-responsive landscape" type="video/mp4" src="https://ternpro-development.s3.amazonaws.com/media/films/69/mobile/2.mp4" data-id="69"></video>

    </div>
</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Would be a lot easier if you nested the popover element inside the element that triggers the hover

Comment: I did try to do this, but my entire code brakes

Comment: providing a working jsfiddle will let people easier on helping you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12014321/how-to-solve-this-hover-out-issue

Answer (score 0):

Add a short [timeout](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) to the closing of the popup. [Clear the time out](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp) when the other div is entered and fire the close when the second div is left.

Comment: This is a pretty standard technique for pop ups and hover effects. Can you host a JS fiddle or something with what you did and maybe we can come up with a solution?